# How to disable the message on preview of Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, messagebox

[image]

This message shows up every time I change something in my code.

I don't want to fix this error. I just want to disable this kind of message to show up all the time.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The message basically says the Preview could not get the style to render with. You could overcome that by selecting a style in the Theme combo box as you have been hinted.

[image: style combo box]

Comment: I know how to fix this error, but the error comes from a component of library and I have no permission to access the code into. As I said in my question, I just wanna disable the message and not to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, it was there I changed :(

Comment: Some exception warnings can be supressed (have you tried to scroll the error?) but I have no other idea..

Comment: yes, like I said. These exception warnings come from a component of a closed library, and I have no access into. It's because of that I just would like to disable this message to appear all the time :/